# Normal bird's eye view

Tags: statistics, multivariable-calculus, gaussian

Considering a top-down view of a two-dimensional Gaussian distribution, how would you statistically define differences on an annulus with the Gaussian's center as its own center, lacking a circle with its center as the Gaussian and size $1$ $z$-score of the $2$D Gaussian and ending at $2$ $z$-score distance from the middle, assuming the standard deviation is uniform across angles?